# Dynamically adding a custom user control to a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol (ascx) that I want to dynamically add to a page.

Neither the control nor the page has a namespace (thanks crappy vendor).

When I use the following, it tells me it cant find the "type or namespace"

```
StayTunedControl = (UserControler_StayTuned)LoadControl("~/UserControler/StayTuned.ascx");           
Page.Controls.Add(StayTunedControl);
StayTunedControl.StayTunedID = Convert.ToInt32(IncludesStayTunedMeta.Value);
```

After some tweaking to the namespaces, etc, I am now at a point where the 3rd line above generates the following error:

'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'StayTunedID'

I was hoping that casting StayTunedControl as type (UserControler_StayTuned) would fix this.

HELP?

Comment: Are you referencing the Control in your aspx file?

Comment: you should update your question with the new information, it makes it easier for people to help with all information in one place.

Comment: added as a reference to the aspx page -- and now I get the following: The compiler failed with error code 1.

Comment: is this web site template or web application template too?

Comment: Derives your ascx from System.Web.UI.UserControl ?
Please add the Control-Directive of the UserControl(starts with <%@ Control) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, had problems with namespaces and remnants being left in the inherits attribute of the control - which was causing the compiler failed with error code 1. message.

Referred to the following for resolution -- matching up with some of the above comments:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LoadingUSerControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing any property of the user control you need to create an instance of the user control when loading it to the page.

```
Dim tc As New Page
Dim c As Control = tc .LoadControl("~/usercontrols/tasks.ascx")
Dim uc As usercontrols_tasks = DirectCast(c, usercontrols_tasks)
```

I first loaded my user control as a generic control. Then created a new instance of the user control and casted the generic loaded control to my uc instance.

After creating an instance of your user control its properties will be available.